# MongoDB $lookup on array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Categories

```json
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("61740086893f048528d166b9"),
        "name": "Category1",
        "tracks" : [ 
            "61c65353565a2d9a1cd3020d", 
            "61c74518962dc3efb96c3438", 
            "61c74775703176a6f72df444"
        ]
    }
```

Tracks

```json
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("61c65353565a2d9a1cd3020d"),
        "name" : "Track1",
        "categoryId" : ObjectId("61740086893f048528d166b9"),
        "creatorId" : ObjectId("61c6478304e98ed63e8ee7d3"),
        "thumbnailId" : ObjectId("61c65353565a2d9a1cd3020c"),
        "plays" : [],
        "media" : {
            "type" : "wav",
            "url" : ""
        },
        "status" : "approved",
        "downloads" : [],
        "uploadedDate" : 1640387411
    }
```

Assuming that I have 5 categories and each category has many tracks ID, I wanna get N last tracks for each category so I used this code below

```js
    categories.aggregate([
        {
            $project: {
                tracks: { $slice: ["$tracks", -2] },
            },
        },
    ]
```

And the response is

```json
    [
        {
            "_id": "61740086893f048528d166b9",
            "tracks": [
                "61c74518962dc3efb96c3438",
                "61c74775703176a6f72df444"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "61740094893f048528d166c1",
            "tracks": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "617400a0893f048528d166cb",
            "tracks": []
        }
    ]
```

So far it's good, but the question is how can I replace each category's tracks from an array of IDs to an array of objects?

I tried `$loopup` but I probably didn't implement the `localField` correctly.

Expected result

```json
    [
        {
            "_id": "61740086893f048528d166b9",
            "tracks": [
                {
                    "_id": ObjectId("61c74518962dc3efb96c3438")
                    ...
                },
                {
                    "_id": ObjectId("61c74775703176a6f72df444")
                    ...
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "61740094893f048528d166c1",
            "tracks": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "617400a0893f048528d166cb",
            "tracks": []
        }
    ]
```

***** UPDATE *****

I'm trying to replace the `creatorId` by `createdBy` which is an object of the users from the `users` collection

Users

```json
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("61c6478304e98ed63e8ee7cb"),
      "email": "USER888@gmail.com",
      "username": "USER999",
      "tracks": [
        ObjectId("61c65353565a2d9a1cd3020d"),
      ],
    }
```

The expected result should be

```json
    [
        {
            "_id": "61740086893f048528d166b9",
            "tracks": [
                {
                    "_id": ObjectId("61c74518962dc3efb96c3438"),
                    "createdBy": {
                        "_id": "userId"
                        ...
                    },
                    ...
                },
                {
                    "_id": ObjectId("61c74775703176a6f72df444"),
                    "createdBy": {
                        "_id": "userId"
                        ...
                    }
                    ...
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "61740094893f048528d166c1",
            "tracks": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "617400a0893f048528d166cb",
            "tracks": []
        }
    ]
```

In addition to the solution below by **ray**, I added the code here https://mongoplayground.net/p/8AjmnL-vhtz

The `createdBy` is at the top level but not under every track

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$lookup` is the correct way for you to find the corresponding object in `Tracks` collection. Why your code does not work is that you are storing strings in `tracks` array in `Categories` collection; while the `_id` of `Tracks` collection is ObjectId. There will be no `$lookup` result as the datatypes do not match. What you can do is converting the strings to ObjectId by using `$toObjectId` in a `$map`, and then do the `$lookup`

```js
db.categories.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      tracks: {
        $slice: [
          "$tracks",
          -2
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      tracks: {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$tracks",
          "as": "t",
          "in": {
            "$toObjectId": "$$t"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "tracks",
      let: {
        t: "$tracks"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              "$in": [
                "$_id",
                "$$t"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "tracks"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TJ-5OOYMKZ4) for your reference.

Comment: thanks for your help, I have one more question, each track has `creatorId`, how can i replace the `creatorId` by `createdBy` which is an object with the user's info? I have a collection of `users`

Comment: @daniel93 the idea is the same. Simply perform a `$lookup` to the `users` collection. You should be fine this time as the `createdBy` is already objectId type. If you need help with a concrete example, please **update your question with the new sample dataset and expected output**.

Comment: updated with mongodb playground link

Comment: @daniel93 try to do the `$lookup` in the subpipeline when `$lookup` tracks, like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Na-MVOXBtGv)

Comment: that's right, I looked where to perform the nested lookup tried couple of things but I missed the pipeline... was confused but I learnt something new! :)